Compare all fields in 2 tables and show fields where values are different
I have 2 tables, the master table and a 'temp' table. The idea is that users can log in and make changes to some data in the master table but the changes are not saved to the master yet but rather a new record is created in the temp table with the values of the record being edited. Mind you the user might have just changed one field so in the newly created record, the values in the master and temp tables will be the same except for one field.
So for the admin to validate the changes made I need to show him which field(s) changed. The solutions I have seen found in my search like this one here compares just a couple of fields using subqueries.
My question is, as I have several fields to compare, do I go this route and create subqueires that compares each field or is there a more elegant way to do this?

Perhaps you could write to the temp table in log style (record_id, attribute_name, old_value, new_value), instead of having to make comparisons?

Thanks @AndhavarapuBalu. I ended up joining the 2 tables and then for my out put I compare the 2 fields and output zero or the actual value. So I did: if(tble1.col1=tble2.col1, 0, tble1.col1) for all columns. So where I have 0, then no change.

What if col1 has a numeric value changing from 2 to 0? The new value 0 would be your "no change" indicator. This may not be possible with your table structure, but worth bearing in mind.

@user1191247, thanks but as long as the the same field in the 2 tables are not the same, it will be caught in the false part of the condition so my output will be the changed value in tble1, which is what I want.
